# Is it correct to say "put the chair through the door at an angle"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

A armchair is too big that we can not put it **straight** through the door, but **at an angle**.

Is it correct to say "**put the armchair through the door at an angle**" in stead of saying "**you can only get the armchair through the door if you put it through at an angle**"?

Comment: Yes, all you've done is made the sentence a command not a request

Comment: What do you mean by "instead"?  Both are correct.  They have different meanings.

Comment: @cruthers, I meant whether I can use the shorter one instead of the longer one.

Comment: Ok. You can always say one thing instead of another, which is why the question is confusing. If you’re asking whether you can say the one instead of the other without affecting the meaning, the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

To my ears, the use of "put" is a little strange. 'Put' is a rather "final" word - it implies leaving  in the place described, which is clearly not the intent here, so I would want to use a more active word, such as 'carry', 'move', 'slide' etc.

Apart from that, the shorter version is a little more succinct, whereas the longer version reads better as you have written it, as it conveys the correct meaning more accurately.